# PostgreSQL connection issue

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin

I am new to PostgreSQL and I am trying to create a connection but I don't know for some reason my connection is not being established.

At first it said that `cant hear the server` so whenever I go in to `task manager` and try to run Postgres servers it says "THE SYSTEM CAN NOT FIND THE FILE SPECIFIED" so I tried to remove Postgres completely from the system but it not completely uninstalling it from my laptop. I think its just remaining some instances in to my laptop which is not letting it to uninstall completely.

[please find the IMAGE here -> click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIbGg.png)

I have attached the image above. Please see that. I have deleted every Postgress thing from my laptop but I think there is still some left in the laptop that is why it is showing this in the services.

Comment: what are the command line options to start the service, and who owns the postgresql data directories?

Comment: prefer using command line to start/stop the server. Try re-installing the postgres 9.x and after changing the default password of _postgres_ user, start the server using command line.

Comment: for linux:  **sudo service postgres start**